# Why the following tfidf vectorization is failing?

Tags: scikit-learn, tf-idf

Hello I am making the following experiment, first I created a vectorizer called: tfidf:

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=10,ngram_range=(1,3),analyzer='word',max_features=500)
```

Then I vectorized the following list:

```
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(listComments)
```

My list of comments looks as follows:

```
listComments = ["hello this is a test","the car is red",...]
```

I tried to save the model as follows:

```
#Saving tfidf
with open('vectorizerTFIDF.pickle','wb') as idxf:
    pickle.dump(tfidf, idxf, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

I would like to use my vectorizer to apply the same tfidf to the following list:

```
lastComment = ["this is a car"]
```

Opening Model:

```
with open('vectorizerTFIDF.pickle', 'rb') as infile:
    tdf = pickle.load(infile)

vector = tdf.transform(lastComment)
```

However I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LDA_test/ldaTest.py", line 141, in <module>
    vector = tdf.transform(lastComment)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 559, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
AttributeError: transform not found
```

I hope someone could support me with this issue thanks in advance,

Comment: You've pickled the vectorized array, not the transformer, you need `   `pickle.dump(tfidf_vectorizer, idxf, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)`

Comment: @maxymoo, thanks a lot for the support could you please post the complete answer I will accept it if this solve my issue thanks for the support,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've pickled the vectorized array, not the transformer, you need `pickle.dump(tfidf_vectorizer, idxf, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)`

Comment: Thanks for your support I am trying again,

Comment: thanks for your support I really  appreciate the help this is working well now,

Comment: @maxymoo Hi I'm getting the same error here but for some reason the solution you have provided doesn't work me. I used the code: ```pickle.dump(model, open('myfilename.sav', 'wb'))``` as well as ```with open('vectorizerTFIDF.pickle','wb') as idxf:
    pickle.dump(tfidf, idxf, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)```, but both give me the same error.