# how to concatenate the following two matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

Hello I have the following matrix called tfidf2, the shape of this matrix is 
(11159, 1985) it has 11159 rows and 1985 columns, I would like to concatenate a new matrix to this one, the matrix called datesNumpy that has a shape of (11159, 12), they have the same number of rows so is possible to concatenate it, the shape of the new matrix called tfidf3 should be (11159,1997),

```
import numpy as np
tfidf2 = tdf.transform(list_cluster)
print("Shape tfidf2",tfidf2.shape)
listAux=[]
for l in listMonth:
        listAux.append([int(y) for y in l])
datesNumpy=np.array([np.array(xi) for xi in listAux])
print("Shape datesNumpy",datesNumpy.shape)
```

I tried:

```
tfidf3=np.stack((tfidf2, datesNumpy), axis=-1)
```

However I got, I appreciate support to overcome this situation:

```
Shape tfidf2 (11159, 1985)
Shape datesNumpy (11159, 12)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 235, in <module>
    tfidf3=np.stack((tfidf2, datesNumpy), axis=-1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 339, in stack
    raise ValueError('all input arrays must have the same shape')
ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape
```

After a feedback from here i tried:

```
tfidf3=np.concatenate([tfidf2, datesNumpy], axis=1)
```

but I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 235, in <module>
    tfidf3=np.concatenate([tfidf2, datesNumpy], axis=1)
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

Comment: `np.hstack` should do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338677/how-to-add-the-following-feature-to-a-tfidf-matrix - This poster was trying `hstack` before.  There's some other information here that we don't know.  `@neo33` - you should be editing your older post, rather than repeating it without little new information.  You are already in dialog with me on that post.

Comment: @hpaulj, thanks for the support what kind of information do you need to help me?, now after to have pure numpy arrays I am trying again thanks for the support

Comment: Ran `tfidf2 =np.zeros((11159, 1985)); datesNumpy =np.zeros((11159, 12)); np.concatenate((tfidf2, datesNumpy), axis=1).shape`. Got `(11159, 1997)` as expected. Your error message leads me to believe that you are not telling us accurate information, so voting to close.

Comment: @Ran I finally achieved the result thanks I had to perform tfidf2=tfidf2.toarray() before everything, sorry for the drawbacks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **numpy.stack(arrays, axis=0)**
>
> Join a sequence of arrays along a new axis.
>
> The axis parameter specifies the index of the new axis in the
> dimensions of the result. For example, if axis=0 it will be the first
> dimension and if axis=-1 it will be the last dimension.
>
> Parameters:
>
> **arrays** : sequence of array_like Each array **must have the same shape**.
>
> **axis** : int, optional The axis in the result array along  which the input arrays are stacked.
>
> Returns:
>
> **stacked** : ndarray The
> stacked array has one more dimension than the input arrays.

According to the documentation must have the same shape.

You must be `concatenate`

Example:

```
tfidf2 = np.zeros((11159, 1985))
datesNumpy = np.ones((11159, 12))

tfidf3=np.concatenate([tfidf2, datesNumpy], axis=1)
print(tfidf3.shape)
```

output:

```
(11159, 1997)
```

Comment: Thanks for the support but I was not able to achieve the desired matrix,

Comment: @neo33 
Are you sure your matrices have data?, print tfidf2.shape and datesNumpy.shape before of  concatenate

Comment: I tried to perform a print and I am getting (11159, 12) (11159, 1985), I believe that maybe it is failing since tfidf2 is an sparse matrix,

Comment: thanks for your support everything was ok I need to add tfidf2=tfidf2.toarray() before to concatenate

Comment: Sparse?  Why didn't you say that 2 questions back?  That makes all the difference.  Sparse matrices have their own 'stack' methods.  I should have push for more information, even an example, of the `tfidf` array.  Pickier people insist on a minimal, verifiable, etc example.

Comment: An earlier question, which I just found, shows that you have already had problems with sparse matrices: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41213978/why-the-following-tfidf-vectorization-is-failing

Comment: thanks for the support I performed tfidf2=tfidf2.toarray() and then I finally achieved the result I think that this issue is related with sklearn,